# Compare coordinate dictionary values if they are in a range of given value

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I am using Python for a few month now, but I got a task, which I cannot accomplish in an efficient, pythonic way.

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{ Apple: [{x: [0, 1, 2, 3], y: [4, 5, 6, 7], z: [8, 9, 0, 1]},
          {x: [2, 3, 4, 5], y: [6, 7, 8, 9], z: [0, 1, 2, 3]}],
 Orange: [{x: [4, 5, 6, 7], y: [8, 9, 1, 0], z: [2, 3, 4, 5]},
          {x: [6, 7, 8, 9], y: [0, 1, 2, 3], z: [4, 5, 6, 7]}]}
```

This is only an example. The dictionary itself has more than two key, and one key has more list elements (coordinates), than 2.

My task is to compare all the key values to all to other key values and found all of those coordinates which are within a given range limit.

For example:
The given range limit is 2:

```
Apple:[{x:[0,3,6,9], y:[7,0,3,6], z:[9,2,5,8]}]
Orange:[{x:[3,6,9,1], y:[4,5,6,9], z:[9,1,10,11]}]
```

Here the z keys first two value are within the range, hence it is a match, which I am looking for.

I could come up with a way, but it is not too efficient and too slow. Can you recommend another way for this?

Here is my code so far:

```
def CompareCoordinates(coordinate_dict):
    key_pairs = []
    error_count = 0
    error_actors = {}

    key_list = sorted(coordinate_dict.keys())
    for ind, val in enumerate(key_list):
        first = key_list[ind]
        for si in range(len(key_list)):
            if si == ind or si < ind:
                continue
            second = key_list[si]
            tmp_list = [first, second]
            key_pairs.append(tmp_list)

    for kp in key_pairs:
        error_actors[f'{kp[0]} - {kp[1]} - OVERLAP'] = []
        error_actors[f'{kp[0]} - {kp[1]} - X'] = []
        error_actors[f'{kp[0]} - {kp[1]} - Y'] = []
        error_actors[f'{kp[0]} - {kp[1]} - Z'] = []

        for fk in coordinate_dict[kp[0]]:
            first_x = fk['x']
            first_y = fk['y']
            first_z = fk['z']

            for sk in coordinate_dict[kp[1]]:
                second_x = sk['x']
                second_y = sk['y']
                second_z = sk['z']

                if first_x == second_x and first_y == second_y and first_z == second_z:
                    error_count += 1
                    error_actors[f'{kp[0]} - {kp[1]} - OVERLAP'].append([coordinate_dict[kp[0]].index(fk)+1, coordinate_dict[kp[1]].index(sk)+1])

                else:
                    diff_x = list(set(first_x).symmetric_difference(set(second_x)))
                    diff_y = list(set(first_y).symmetric_difference(set(second_y)))
                    diff_z = list(set(first_z).symmetric_difference(set(second_z)))

                    if diff_x:
                        if float(abs(diff_x[0] - diff_x[1])) <= difference:
                            error_count += 1
                            error_actors[f'{kp[0]} - {kp[1]} - X'].append([f'{coordinate_dict[kp[0]].index(fk) + 1}. coordinate', f'{coordinate_dict[kp[1]].index(sk) + 1}. coordinate'])
                    if diff_y:
                        if float(abs(diff_y[0] - diff_y[1])) <= difference:
                            error_count += 1
                            error_actors[f'{kp[0]} - {kp[1]} - Y'].append([f'{coordinate_dict[kp[0]].index(fk) + 1}. coordinate', f'{coordinate_dict[kp[1]].index(sk) + 1}. coordinate'])
                    if diff_z:
                        if float(abs(diff_z[0] - diff_z[1])) <= difference:
                            error_count += 1
                            error_actors[f'{kp[0]} - {kp[1]} - Z'].append([f'{coordinate_dict[kp[0]].index(fk) + 1}. coordinate', f'{coordinate_dict[kp[1]].index(sk) + 1}. coordinate'])


    error_actors = {k: v for k, v in error_actors.items() if v}
    return error_count, error_actors
```

Comment: Where do you get the output from? Neither of those dictionaries is in your example input... Also what do you mean by "found all of those coordinates which are within a given range limit"

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your task correctly you want to find all the values of each key such that the absolute value of all the differences have the property that the distance from one value to the other is no more than the range limit.

Start with a simpler problem: how can you do it if you have just a list ?

You could use a comparison with  `min` and `max` values in the list, but here we take the "loops route" because it is better in the case of your problem :

```
values = [1,2,5,2,1,7,3,4,1,8]
n = 3
min_v = max_v = values[0]

for x in values:
    if abs(max_v - min_v) > n : 
        print("Range limit exceeded")
        break
    else :
        if x < min_v : min_v = x
        elif x > max_v : max_v = x
else :
    print("All values are within the range")
```

You can apply the same method to your problem but you need to make it coordinate by coordinate and if you want to do it efficiently for every coordinate at the same time while you loop through `coordinate_dict`.

Comment: @pizzahunter_49 did you find a way through?